# Find and delete empty folders recursively without "-empty" parameter

Tags: android, find, sh

I found bunch of examples to solve my problem, BUT android find utility and busybox find utility quite old and says:

```
A0001:/sdcard # find . -empty -type d
find: bad arg '-empty'
```

So, i can't find solution without usage "-empty" arg. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Pretty unclear what you try to achieve.

Comment: question looks like unrelated to Android development. It themes like linux question.

Comment: The version of `find` is not necessarily old; `-empty` is an extension to the POSIX standard and not guaranteed to be part of a conforming implementation of `find`.

Comment: greenapps, i tried to find solution to clear sdcard of my phone from trees of empty folders.

Comment: Vlad Matvienko, i didn't say this is about Android development. It's about android environment. Maybe i marked incorrect tag, sorry.

Comment: chepner, maybe you're right, but i see that utility find doesn't understand "-empty" argument, so i decided that smth wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rmdir` command which need the directory must be empty.

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -print -exec rmdir {} 2>/dev/null \;
```

Redirect the error message to null device, use `maxdepth` to avoid too deep to search.

Comment: seems working but this command doesn't include hidden directories, i see solution _find . -name ".*" -type f_ but how to do it in one string?

Comment: working on linux, dowsn't working on phone... can't get why

Comment: find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -print - this part is working as well

Comment: _find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -print - delete_ i think this string works as i wish, thank you

Comment: @sergentum But why on my android shell,  `-delete` option is not available?

Comment: who can say? maybe try to install bysobox (need root) and try execute "busybox find"?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Neither in. Termux, nor in a "normal" console. `find . -maxdepth 20 -type d -print 2>/dev/null \;` just gives me no output, without the `\;` it outputs every folder.